# Color the lowest negative value

Tags: google-sheets

I have this custom conditional formula to color the lowest value in a range:

```
=E5:E35=MIN(E$5:E$35)
```

Is there a way to add a condition to this formula? What I want is to color the lowest value but ONLY if this value is less than 0 ... If all values in this range are positives, then do not color anything.

Answer (score 1):

Use Conditional Formatting and set:

- Range to E5:E35 Format cells if...
- to Custom formula is the formula is
- =AND($E5<0, $E5=MIN($E5:$E35))

And set the color as required.

Comment: For some reason, it's coloring other values too, not just the lowest negative one, check here -- http://imgur.com/a/Z88BJ

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way in E5 to pick up future rows:

Range: E5:E
Custom formula is: =and(E5=min(E5),E5<0)

Answer (score 0):

I did a workaround, I wrote this formula in another cell:

```
=ArrayFormula(MIN(IF(E5:E35<0;E5:E35)))
```

And I set the conditional formula to color the value that matches this cell.